# How to view logs on anchor rust client

Tags: rust, anchor-client, logs

I am trying to send a transaction to my program through rust client. But i am running into an issue and i would like to see the logs so that i can trace it.

I am using the anchor rust client and following the example below.

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/client/example/src/blocking.rs#L182

Running the test, i get the following error.

```
Error: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction [2 log messages]

Caused by:
    0: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction [2 log messages]
    1: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction [2 log messages]
test tests::test_deliver ... FAILED
```

How can i view the log messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you boot the local validator yourself in another terminal using `solana-test-validator`, then in *another* terminal subscribe to the logs using `solana logs -ul`, then you can run `anchor test --skip-local-validator` and see the full transaction log.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the above method didnt return the logs of the failed transaction. Before doing a tx to my program, i do an airdrop which is successful. So i can only see the airdrop tx as the last transaction in the logs and there is no logs about the tx to my program which is what i need.

Comment: Ohh yeah try it with `skipPreflight: true`

Comment: Where should i add the above?

Comment: You can use [this alternative `send` method](https://docs.rs/anchor-client/latest/anchor_client/struct.RequestBuilder.html#method.send_with_spinner_and_config), which takes [`RpcSendTransactionConfig`](https://docs.rs/solana-client/latest/solana_client/rpc_config/struct.RpcSendTransactionConfig.html) and has the field in it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the logs from JS/TS, for example you need to so an assertion in your tests, you can use [`getLogs()` from the Solana helpers module](https://github.com/solana-developers/helpers?tab=readme-ov-file#get-the-logs-for-a-transaction).

Since you're using Anchor, get the web3.js `connection` object from your Anchor provider:

```
const connection = program.provider.connection;
```

Then just:

```
const logs = await getLogs(connection, tx);
```

Logs is an array of strings.